# How can I get the values of a multidimensional array given its key?

Tags: php

Example:

```
$animal = ("bird" => "crow", "cat" => "lion", "snake" => "cobra");
```

I want to get all values whose keys are

```
function_name_get_value(["monkey","goat","bird"]);
```

I tried using `array_key_exists()` but the problem is I cannot pass the `$animal` variable since it is specified what arguments are to be passed on function `function_name_get_value`

Comment: First that is not an multidimensional array. Second the syntax of this line: `unction_name_get_value(["monkey","goat","bird"]);` is not correct. And you can just do `$animal['monkey']` to get the values. What is it exactly what you try to do?

Comment: Multidimensional array is an array like: array('a' => array('b')), your $animal array is a flat one. As sirwilliam mentioned you can access array elements as $animal['monkey']. If you need a function to return the values for given keys then you'll need to use $_GLOBAL array which is a bad practice.

Comment: @sirwilliam: The sytax of the array isn't correct, but square brackets are fine since PHP 5.4.

Comment: I'm finding this question confusing - it seems to me from what you've described that you're trying to filter an array by an array of keys. If so, you could try looking at using http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php

Comment: @minitech *u*k me you are right! I still use php 5.3.9 so didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple you just need to pass 2 arguments one is name of key and second is array.

```
function getValue($arr, $key)
{
   return isset($arr[$key]) && is_array($arr) ? $arr[$key] : false;
}
```

if you want get more keys just use loop.

```
function getValue($arr, $keyArr)
{
   if(!is_array($arr) || !is_array($keyArr)) return false;

   $found = array();
   foreach($keyArray as $key)
   if(array_key_exists($key, $arr)) $found[$key] = $arr[$key];
   return $found;
}
```

[array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists) needs two arguments one is keyname and second is array. I don't see any other option to find a key in array. You must pass 2 parametrs at least

Comment: the problem specify that the only argument is ["monkey","goat","bird"].

Comment: I don't want to write it but the solution for you is to use **$_GLOBALS** keyword ;/ are you sure you cannot pass the other argument in way I've proposed? What is the body of this function why do you need to use it? http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php